# Using Regex to get a find a word at the beginning of a line in a file

Tags: javascript, regex

What I need to do is find every occurrence of the word "prompt" at the beginning of a line in a sql script file.  For instance in these sql scripts we will have anywhere from 1 to many occurrences of the word "prompt" at the beginning of each line.  I need to pull these "prompt" words with regex but without pulling the word "prompt" from anywhere else it may occur in the sql script.  Thank you for your help

Here is an example of what a script could look like.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WORD_WRAPPED
CL SCR
undef database_service
SET trimspool ON
set linesize 1000
COLUMN LATEST_PROCESS_DATE NEW_VALUE LATEST_DATE
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') LATEST_PROCESS_DATE FROM dual;
spool ..\log\R_AssetMgmtITDB_EntitlementTestPrompt_Oracle_1.0_&latest_date..lst
prompt
prompt LOGIN TO entitlement(DB => toolit - IT, tooluat - PCU, toolprd - PROD)
prompt
conn entitlement@&&database_service
show user
prompt database_name IS &&database_service
prompt
@schema\DML\insert_amportal_entitlements_entitlementTestPrompt.sql
undef database_service
undef userid
undef response
prompt end of R_AssetMgmtITDB_EntitlementTestPrompt_Oracle_1.0
```

Comment: `^prompt\b` , pls do a search before asking.

Comment: What about `prompting`, and what about case sensitive?

Comment: The best way is to use _multi-line_ mode. In this mode the `^` anchor means beginning of line, not beginning of string. Would still match the beginning of string as it considers it just another line.

Comment: This did not work in a regex tester

Answer (score 1):

"\nprompt " can also be used .

Comment: Except for the beginning of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression `/^prompt\b/i` either in multi-line mode or by splitting the string on new lines:

Splitting the string can give you the line numbers the word occurs on:

```js
var string = "SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WORD_WRAPPED\nCL SCR\nundef database_service\nSET trimspool ON\nset linesize 1000\nCOLUMN LATEST_PROCESS_DATE NEW_VALUE LATEST_DATE\nSELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') LATEST_PROCESS_DATE FROM dual;\nspool ..\log\R_AssetMgmtITDB_EntitlementTestPrompt_Oracle_1.0_&latest_date..lst\nprompt\nprompt LOGIN TO entitlement(DB => toolit - IT, tooluat - PCU, toolprd - PROD)\nprompt\nconn entitlement@&&database_service\nshow user\nprompt database_name IS &&database_service\nprompt\n@schema\DML\insert_amportal_entitlements_entitlementTestPrompt.sql\nundef database_service\nundef userid\nundef response\nprompt end of R_AssetMgmtITDB_EntitlementTestPrompt_Oracle_1.0";

var answer =
  string.split('\n')
        .map(function(v, i) { return { lineNumber: i, value: v }; })
        .filter(function(v) { return /^prompt\b/i.test(v.value); });

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = JSON.stringify( answer );
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
```

Just using the regular expression can also give you the matches:

```js
var string = "SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WORD_WRAPPED\nCL SCR\nundef database_service\nSET trimspool ON\nset linesize 1000\nCOLUMN LATEST_PROCESS_DATE NEW_VALUE LATEST_DATE\nSELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') LATEST_PROCESS_DATE FROM dual;\nspool ..\log\R_AssetMgmtITDB_EntitlementTestPrompt_Oracle_1.0_&latest_date..lst\nprompt\nprompt LOGIN TO entitlement(DB => toolit - IT, tooluat - PCU, toolprd - PROD)\nprompt\nconn entitlement@&&database_service\nshow user\nprompt database_name IS &&database_service\nprompt\n@schema\DML\insert_amportal_entitlements_entitlementTestPrompt.sql\nundef database_service\nundef userid\nundef response\nprompt end of R_AssetMgmtITDB_EntitlementTestPrompt_Oracle_1.0";
var re     = /^prompt\b/gim;
var answer = string.match( re );

document.getElementById( "out" ).innerHTML = JSON.stringify( answer );
```

```html
<p id="out"/>
```